# How to stop app loading before getcurrentposition has data?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I have some code that detects the location and returns the longitude and latitude. It stores these values in a variable and then adds these to a URL which is then used to open a webview. The problem I'm having is that it takes the app a few milleseconds before it has the location date, and then when the app loads the webview the coordinates come out as "undefined" as the location data hasn't been received. If I create an alert and echo the URL with the coordiantes, and then set a timeout (1 millesecond works) then the alert will print the correct information.

I've tried setting a timeout on the buttons that create the webviews instead but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there another approach I could take? Thank you

```
var coords;

Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
    if (e.error) { 
       alert('Error: ' + e.error); 
    } else { 
       coords = e.coords.latitude;
    } 
});


setTimeout(function() {
 alert("http://mywebsite.com/api/return-latlong/"+coords);
}, 500);


// Keep track of selected button and our button views
var buttonIdx = 0,
buttons=[]; 

// Definition of buttons to generate
var buttonsToCreate = [
{icon: '/images/icon1.png', icon2: '/images/icon1.png', name: "Webview1", url: "http://http://mywebsite.com/test.php?"+coords},
{icon: '/images/icon1.png', icon2: '/images/icon1.png', name: "Webview2", url: "http://mywebsite.com/page1"},
{icon: '/images/icon1.png', icon2: '/images/icon1.png', name: "Webview3", url: "http://mywebsite.com/page2"},
];



// Open Window

$.index.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your website url inside the getCurrentLocation's callback method. because out side of that you can't predict that how much time it will take to get current location.

```
Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
    if (e.error) { 
       alert('Error: ' + e.error); 
    } else { 
       coords = e.coords.latitude;
       alert("http://mywebsite.com/api/return-latlong/"+coords);
    } 
});
```

Comment: I understand that, thank you. But is there a way of holding the loading of the app until the location has been detected?

Comment: Yes you can use "Titanium.UI.ActivityIndicator". For more information [Red this](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ActivityIndicator)

Comment: That just seems to be a loading gif that I can add to the app? I want to actually stop the app loading until it has the location.

Comment: No you can't use gif for loading. You can use activity indicator for loading, just start when you call the geolocation for getting current location and hide the activity indicator when you got the response from geolocation.

Comment: As far as I can see Titanium.UI.ActivityIndicator is for adding a loading animation while some code is loading. This is not what I'm trying to achieve, I am trying to stop the code from loading so that getCurrentPosition has time to find the location. Currently the rest of the app is loading before getCurrentPosition has time to get the location. Please correct me if I'm wrong, thank you.

Comment: If you want to stop the some code execution util you get current location than you can add that code into getCurrentLocation's Call back function. Other wise you can't stop the code execution. If you still have any doubt tell me fell free.